# Extract a specific value from an output stream in bash

Tags: bash, curl

I have this command:

```
`curl -X POST https://server.domain.com/v2/jobs/$job_ID/runs?project_id=$project_ID -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}"  -d "{ \"job_run\": {} }"
```

and it gives this output

> quote
> Response from job execution is {"metadata":{"rov":{"mode":0,"collaborator_ids":{}},"project_id":"aff59748-260a-476e-9578-b4f4a93e7a92","sandbox_id":"aff59748-260a-476e-9578-b4f4a93e7a92","usage":{"last_updated_at":"2021-02-12T00:31:19Z","last_updater_id":"1000331040","last_update_time":1613089879840,"last_accessed_at":"2021-02-12T00:31:19Z","last_access_time":1613089879840,"last_accessor_id":"1000331040","access_count":0},"name":"Notebook Job","description":"","tags":[],"asset_type":"job_run","origin_country":"us","rating":0,"total_ratings":0,"catalog_id":"d47cd45c-0161-4b89-ba4f-c0e48272f08e","created":1613089879840,"created_at":"2021-02-12T00:31:19Z","owner_id":"1000331040","size":0,"version":2,"asset_state":"available","asset_attributes":["job_run"],**"asset_id":"5d9dae4e-0dfe-4e53-9e56-18a4bb44af"**,"asset_category":"USER"},"entity":{"job_run":{"job_ref":"28723316-9373-44ba-9229-7c796f21b099","job_name":"Dummy Job for E2E Testing","job_type":"notebook","state":"Starting","isScheduledRun":false,"configuration":{"env_id":"jupconda37-aff59748-260a-476e-9578-b4f4a93e7a92","version":"ca0b9a58-ba0d-4d28-93d5-3cdc66a5b137","env_type":"notebook","env_variables":[],"job_manager_id":"9268a8a8-72e4-47a1-a851-65f38d8284ce","notebook_job_output":{},"command_line_arguments":[]},"project_name":"Tahoe Migration"}},"href":"/v2/assets/5d9dae4e-0dfe-4e53-9e56-ee18a4bb44af?project_id=aff59748-260a-476e-9578-b4f4a93e7a92"}

I want to extract the value of **asset_id** from the output stream and store it in a variable within shell script. I tried storing the response in a bash variable and tried to parse with awk, it didn't work. Could one of you please provide me an idea as to how to go about this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jq` is much better for processing json, although you need to strip off the "quote Response from job execution is " prefix first. Something like this:

```
response=$(curl ...)
asset_id=$(echo "${response#*Response from job execution is }" | jq -r '.metadata.asset_id')
```

Comment: THanks a lot Gordon. It worked like a charm. You Sir are god sent to help folks like us. I couldn't figure this out after trying for hours. Hmm this jq tool is the magic, never knew about it. You really saved me from a lot of manual work. Thank you once again. God bless you

Comment: I accepted the answer now. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only thing you need, you can solve it with `sed`:

```
<YOUR_CURL> | sed 's/.*"asset_id":"\([0-9a-z\-]*\)".*/\1/'
```